# Does SignalR version difference matter between asp.net core and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an asp.net core web API application. This application broadcasts the message via SignalR.

And I have a .Net framework WPF client application. So I used asp.net signalr in this project to connect asp.net core signalR.

Is this a problem? Should those two projects be .net core application? Because connection is always failing.

Comment: Core SignalR client needs to be used to talk to Core SignalR server. Non-core SignalR needs to be used to talk to non-Core SignalR server.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to communicate between a client and a server your SignalR should be the same version, so for example if your SignalR server is ASP.NET Core you need to use the ASP.NET core SignalR client. It works the other way arround as well so if the server is ASP.NET you need the ASP.NET client.

Comment: Server is asp.net core and client is WPF on .net framework. So this is so bad stuation.